# Regular expression match, then replace?

Tags: php, regex

Say I have something like:

```
&page=4
```

I want to replace this and make it blank, so it doesn't exist.

But that page number could be anything, 66, 98, 17, 2, 109, etc.

Currently I have something along the lines of:

```
$currentpage = str_replace("&page=", "", $currentpage);
```

But I need it to also remove the number, how do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$currentpage = preg_replace("/&page=\d+/", "", $currentpage);
```

But if you are creating this yourself, you ought to do...

```
$get = $_GET;

unset($get['page']);

echo http_build_query($get);
```

This will output all the GET params nicely serialised a string. When you unset the `page` member, it obviously won't appear :)

Comment: That works great, how would I do it if &sort=lowest (remove this whole thing) - as the one you posted only seems to work for numeric characters. Do I just use w+ as opposed to d+?

Comment: @Kyle You could change it to `&sort=[^&$]`.

Comment: the dollar sign in `[^&$]` doesn't make sense. Inside the character class it's a literal dollar sign. To get equivalent functionality as "not end of string" you have to do something like: `(?!&|$)` ... I'd just leave it out altogether :)